# How to handle SSO authentication login using Jmeter

Tags: authentication, jmeter, single-sign-on, performance-testing, saml

I want to perform performance test on a web application. It has SSO authentication during login.
My Jmeter scripts are failing because of the SSO authentication. Kindly advise if Jmeter can handle SSO authentication? If Yes then how?

I tried correlation in the POST method as shown in the image below but it is failing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0Xbu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, JMeter can simulate [SAML SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language#Profiles) login, you just need to [correlate](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter) **all** the dynamic parameters. Those which are missing are:

- `authencity_token`
- `xsrfProtection`

See [How to Load Test SAML SSO Secured Websites with JMeter](https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-load-test-saml-sso-secured-websites-with-jm) article for more information.